# version 3.11 | AWS installation fails due to HTTPS / x509 issues on waiting for control pane

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, openshift, x509certificate, okd

Trying to do an openshift 3.11 install with 3 master setup ,2 infra and 2 nodes. I didn't use a LB node since I figured the AWS ELB would take care of that for me.

My current issue is the installation will fail on the wait for control pane task.

```
failed: [ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal] (item=etcd) => {"attempts": 60, "changed": false, "item": "etcd", "msg": {"cmd": "/usr/bin/oc get pod master-etcd-ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal -o json -n kube-system"
```

Different errors shown below

I've done the following.

Because this is only a demon system I wanted to go the cheap route and create self signed certs. So i ran the following

```
openssl rew -new -key openshift.key -out openshift.csr
openssl req -new -key openshift.key -out openshift.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 1095 -in openshift.csr -signkey openshift.key -out openshift.crt
```

then within my hosts file i added the following

```
openshift_master_named_certificates=[{"certfile": "/home/ec2-user/certs/openshift.crt", "keyfile": "/home/ec2-user/certs/openshift.key"}]
```

Next I created an ELB accepting HTTP traffic on port 8443 and directing it to HTTP 8443 to any of the masters.
When I do this I get the following fail when re-running the command which is failing the task

```
[root@ip-10-0-4-29 ~]# /usr/bin/oc get pod master-etcd-ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal -o json -n kube-system
Unable to connect to the server: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

If i change the ELB to take http traffic and direct it to HTTPS 8443 I ge the following error

```
[root@ip-10-0-4-29 ~]# /usr/bin/oc get pod master-etcd-ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal -o json -n kube-system
The connection to the server os.domain-name.net:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

If I try to change the ELB to accept HTTPS traffic I needed to copy the [guide to create SSL certs to use in aws](https://hackernoon.com/easy-lets-encrypt-certificates-on-aws-79387767830b) but even then accepting HTTPS traffic on 8443 and sending it either via HTTP or HTTPS to 8443 on the master node results in this error

```
 [root@ip-10-0-4-29 ~]# /usr/bin/oc get pod master-etcd-ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal -o json -n kube-system
 Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've also copy in my hosts file just incase I've something off with it.
    # Create an OSEv3 group that contains the master, nodes, etcd, and lb groups.
    # The lb group lets Ansible configure HAProxy as the load balancing solution.
    # Comment lb out if your load balancer is pre-configured.
    [OSEv3:children]
    masters
    nodes
    etcd

```
# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_deployment_type=origin


openshift_cloudprovider_aws_access_key="{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
openshift_cloudprovider_aws_secret_key="{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
openshift_clusterid=openshift
openshift_cloudprovider_kind=aws

openshift_hosted_manage_registry=true
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_kind=object
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_provider=s3
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_accesskey="{{ lookup('env','AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_secretkey="{{ lookup('env','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_bucket=os-test-os-bucket
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_region=us-west-2
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_chunksize=26214400
openshift_hosted_registry_storage_s3_rootdirectory=/registry
openshift_hosted_registry_pullthrough=true
openshift_hosted_registry_acceptschema2=true
openshift_hosted_registry_enforcequota=true
openshift_hosted_registry_replicas=3

#openshift_enable_excluders=false
openshift_disable_check=memory_availability
openshift_additional_repos=[{'id': 'centos-okd-ci', 'name': 'centos-okd-ci', 'baseurl' :'https://rpms.svc.ci.openshift.org/openshift-origin-v3.11', 'gpgcheck' :'0', 'enabled' :'1'}]

openshift_node_groups=[{'name': 'node-config-master', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true']}, {'name': 'node-config-infra', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true']}, {'name': 'node-config-compute', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true']}]
openshift_router_selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true'
openshift_registry_selector='node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true'
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=true


openshift_master_named_certificates=[{"certfile": "/home/ec2-user/certs/openshift.crt", "keyfile": "/home/ec2-user/certs/openshift.key"}]



# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider'}]

# Native high availability cluster method with optional load balancer.
# If no lb group is defined installer assumes that a load balancer has
# been preconfigured. For installation the value of
# openshift_master_cluster_hostname must resolve to the load balancer
# or to one or all of the masters defined in the inventory if no load
# balancer is present.
openshift_master_cluster_method=native
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=os.domain-name.net
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=os.domain-name.net

# host group for masters

[masters]
ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal
ip-10-0-5-54.us-east-2.compute.internal
ip-10-0-6-8.us-east-2.compute.internal

[etcd]
ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal
ip-10-0-5-54.us-east-2.compute.internal
ip-10-0-6-8.us-east-2.compute.internal


[nodes]

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]

#master
ip-10-0-4-29.us-east-2.compute.internal  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
ip-10-0-5-54.us-east-2.compute.internal  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'
ip-10-0-6-8.us-east-2.compute.internal  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master'

#infra
ip-10-0-4-28.us-east-2.compute.internal openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra'
ip-10-0-5-241.us-east-2.compute.internal openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra'


#node
ip-10-0-4-162.us-east-2.compute.internal openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
ip-10-0-5-146.us-east-2.compute.internal openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
```

Please if anyone can help me get past this hurdle so I can finally try and demo out a CI/CD pipeline using Openshift I'd be truly grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old link but I was running into the same issue with my ELB configured as HTTPS.  I changed the listener to TCP and used port 443 for the Load Balancer Port and the Instance Port.  For the Health Check, make sure you are using Ping Protocol HTTPS, Ping Port 443 and Ping Path of "/" . Those configuration changes allowed the installation to proceed.